# How to enable Java Run Time Environment on Windows 7?

Tags: java, firefox, plugins, applet, jvm

Currently, I am working on mini java applet. However, when I opened my applet in my FireFox, it said Java is disabled and there is no option to enable it at all. I am aware of the vulnerability of the JVM. If enabling JVM is not possible, how can I test my java applet.

Comment: Consider switching to Javascript.  Your potential users will have the same problems and will not be willing to change things.

Comment: Have you checked the Java Deplayment Toolkit plugin in Add-ons->Plugins?

Comment: Yes, I have and there are two options - Ask to activate and never activate. It is already set to "Ask to activate." Firefox doesn't ask anything when I open my applet, but you do see the applet placeholder with big x and "plugin disabled."

Comment: +1 to SLaks. I'm a relative power user (as are most people here, I'd guess), and I've never bothered to set up Java in my browser. If a site requires it, I just hit the back button and go on with my day.

Comment: I 100% agree. I am like that too. If a website doesn't work when you click on the link or go to an URL, I move on and it only takes 10 seconds for me. :)

Comment: @SLaks Even when you are right you are not answering the right question

Comment: @yshavit Applets still live at some level, for example my bank's online banking service is provided with an applet